# How to make CheckBoxes in a TreeView readonly in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone help me because I want to disable the checkboxes in a treeview and at the same time be able to scroll through the treeview.

Comment: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Comment: winforms? wpf ? asp.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class and copy the code below

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
public class MyTreeView
Inherits Treeview
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m as system.Windows.Forms.Message)
if m.Msg = &H203 THEN
m.Result = IntPtr.Zero
else
MyBase.WndProc(m)
End If
End Sub
```

Compile your project and either drag and drop this new control from your toolbox or go to your designer and rename System.Windows.Forms.Treeview to MyTreeview.

Go to your vb Code and on BeforeCheck event say e.Cancel = true

Done!!!

If you need any help post your comment.